# Running processes at the same time on the Target xml object (csproj file)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

I was thinking how I could run multiples processes (setting up the dependencies to achieve the final result) in a just dotnet custom command.

I quickly found the `target` xml object that I can setup in the `.csproj` file.

So this is what I tried:

```
<Target Name="fuzz" BeforeTargets="Run">
    <Exec Command="docker run --name dumpsql -v C:\path\to\postgres1.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgres1.sql --env POSTGRES_DB=postgres --env POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postdocker -p 5432:5432 -d postgres:latest"/>
    <Exec Command="dotnet run"/>
    <Exec Command="docker run --name fuzzcontainer schemathesis/schemathesis:stable run --cassette-path /app/cassete.yaml --checks all http://host.docker.internal:5169/swagger/v1/swagger.json"/>
</Target>
```

Then I could run `dotnet msbuild /t:fuzz`

The problem:

- Stop in the second `Exec`, probably, because the dotnet program is still running and it didn't return any code.

So how can I force the build to move on to the next `Exec` without waiting for a returned code?

Thank you all.

Comment: The `Exec` task always uses a `cmd` shell on Windows. You may be able to use the [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) command to start separate processes. You won't know when the process has been completed and you won't have the exit code.

Comment: @JonathanDodds Hi. Thank you for your reply. I also tried to launch the dotnet program in background using the `start` command as you said `start /b dotnet run`, but it didn't work as well

Comment: In fact, once you open the task manager and you see those `.NET host` processes in background, and then you proceed to end those tasks it's like a trigger, because the next `Exec` will start.

Comment: Are you putting all the `start`s in one batch command or batch file? Does `start "" dotnet run` work?

Comment: The [`MSBuild` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task?view=vs-2022) supports parallelism across projects, e.g. `<MSBuild Projects="a.csproj;b.csproj;c.csproj" BuildInParallel="true"/>`.

Comment: You could write a custom task to start separate processes.

Comment: The `start "" dotnet run` doesn't work. Answering to your question I'm putting the start in one command.

Comment: About the `BuildInParallel`. the `.csproj` pretty much will start at the same time, I want to have the web Api ready (dotnet run), to be able to make requests with the third `Exec`.

Comment: @JonathanDodds So what you saying is to make a `class` extending the `task` and using it in the `.csproj` file? Well that could be a solution

Comment: I would suggest an inline task - ["MSBuild inline tasks with RoslynCodeTaskFactory"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-roslyncodetaskfactory?view=vs-2022)

Comment: @NunoDomingues You can take a look of my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce your situation:

[image]

And this is the way I use to avoid the situation:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="fuzz" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="echo xxx"/>
    <!--<Exec Command="dotnet run"/>-->
    <Exec Command="dotnet run > output.log 2> error.log"/>
    <Exec Command="echo yyy"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

The key is:

`dotnet run > output.log 2> error.log`

In this way, I can continue my steps and the dotnet run unable to block me any more.

The outputs will be generated into two files.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ohh, I get it. You triggered by writing the logs to a file and so your program will move on. Thank you @Bowman Zhu-MSFT

Comment: @NunoDomingues Hi, if my answer was helpful to your situation, please [mark it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to end this question. This will be helpful to others who meet the similar question and seeking for the answer. :)

Comment: I marked you question as accepted